# Can you define main() to take in more than argc/argv arguments?

Tags: c++, c

Can you define main() to take multiple arguments, for example:

```
int main(int argc1, int argc2, char* argv1[], int* argv2[])
```

Comment: What should these extra arguments be? Where do they come from?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but your program will not be standard anymore.  You will need to modify the part of the OS that calls your `main` and also modify the compiler to accept your new syntax.  Most operating systems already have a convention of passing command line arguments to an executable.

Comment: C or C++? Different languages with different rules.

Comment: there is a (very little used) std format where a third parameter is used, where that third parameter is a ptr to the environment information.  However, since the OS will only pass a standard format, (and I expect you do not want to re-write the relevant part of the OS), the answer is 'NO'

Comment: @user3629249: The 3-parameter form is not defined by the C standard, though it's mentioned in Annex J as a common extension. POSIX doesn't require support for it either

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C, the only *portable* definitions for `main` are:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

or equivalent. Other implementation-defined forms are permitted -- but as the term "implementation-defined" implies, they're permitted *only* if your compiler chooses to permit them.

There are some common extensions, such as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) { /* ... */ }
```

but I doubt that any compiler supports the particular form you suggest. I'm not sure how it would be useful; the existing `argc`/`argv` form allows arbitrarily many command-line arguments.

C++ is slightly different from C in that it requires the return type to be `int`; in C, a compiler may, but need not, permit other return types. Also, in C++ `()` means that a function has no parameters, equivalent to C's `(void)`. (C++ also permits `(void)` for C compatibility.)

Comment: Nice answer. Note: `envp[]` is usually a `NULL` terminated array.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler gets to make the decision of what signatures (and return type) of `main` are allowed, and what the behaviour of the program is for each one. Consult its documentation to find out about this.

The only signatures that all compilers must support are the two standard ones (and equivalent):

```
int main(void)
int main(int, char **)
```

Answer (score 1):

[basic.start.main]/2:

> An implementation shall not predefine the `main` function. This
>   function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a declared return type
>   of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. An
>   implementation shall allow both
>
> - a function of () returning `int` and
> - a function of `(int`, pointer to pointer to `char)`returning `int`
>
> as the type of `main` (8.3.5).

An implementation could theoretically allow the signature mentioned in the question - but it would be quite nonsensical, and it seems that no relevant compiler supports it. (What would it pass?)

Although there are certain signatures of `main` that are indeed supported and not covered by standard, e.g.:

```
int main( int, char**, char** )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have the `main` function signature any way you want it; but it will not be standard.

You will have to change the compiler to accept your new declaration. And emit the proper code for it.

You may have to change the operating system to correctly pass the arguments from the User to your program.

Again, yes, other declarations are *possible*, but **they will not be standard** and require modifications to OS and tool chain.